# Can't use css to replace background image with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, background-image

using Bootstrap 3, I'm trying to substitute a smaller image for a larger for small devices.

With this code I get nothing. If I put the image src in the html, then I see both images in certain views. Do I have to specify a div size for this to work?

html:

```
    <div><img id="logo"></div>
```

css:

```
    #logo {background-image: url('../images/logo.svg'); }

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    #logo {background-image: url('../images/logo-small.svg'); }
    }
```

Comment: You set the background on the `<div>` and remove the `<img>` tag completely.  You can't have an `<img>` tag without a source.  Or you use the media query to resize the img.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the background-image, it doesn't change the image's `src` attribute, but only the image-background.

You can simply display the image directly as the div's background (and ignore the img element):

```
<div id="logo"></div>

 #logo {
   background-image: url('../images/logo.svg');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:cover;
   width:200px;/*your image width*/
   height:60px;/*your image height*/
}
```

And then you'll have to set the div's width and height of course.

There is no cross-browser solution to change the src attribute of an image directly from CSS (which is considered content and not style).

Some browsers will support css rule `content-url` but others will not (like Firefox).
It will look like so:

```
#yourimageid {
 content:url(yourimage.jpg);
}
```

But again, it is not a cross-browser solution.

Another good alternative will be using Javascript/jQuery to change the `src` attribute directly.

```
$('#logo').attr('src','yourimage.jpg');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but since I want this to be responsive, I can't set fixed widths of divs and even images, right? I'll look for a javascript solution, thanks

Comment: @Chris Actually, using the image as the div's background IS considered responsive. You can set the div to any size you want. I just added you the jQuery example as well :)

Comment: jquery seems so much easier - but how do I specify it only for a phone-type viewpoint?

Comment: @Chris That's when jQuery becomes more tricky...there's no native way of doing it expect for checking screen size or using a 3rd party library, which is an overkill for this task. I suggest using the first CSS example I gave you...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you got your answer or not; this may be helpful.

If you wanna change background image of element to suit two devices with different dimensions with CSS, just create two CSS files. one for small device and another for  larger one and use the following code so that the browser does what you want(every device has it's own CSS file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-device-width: 420px)" href="css/style_420.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-device-width: 768px)" href="css/style_768.css">
```

you can change value of media attribute according to your will. for example, if your page is supposed to be rendered on device with 420px and in landscape orientation, you can use this:

```
<link media="(max-width: 420px) and (orientation: landscape)" href="css/style_420_l.css">
```

This link may helps: **http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/**

Don't forget to put this tag in your page header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

For changing the content value, this link helps: **http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/**

It's logical that create global css file, that contains commons, for all devices and separated files for each one.